# LXD - Assign public IP to a container

Tags: networking, virtualization, ip, network-bridge, lxd

I have several static public IP addresses on my host machine. I want to assign that IP to a certain container, but I cannot really find any updated info about that. I tried to create a new network, with the secondary IP and assign it to a container, however after doing it, container loses internet connection.

What I did:

```
lxc network create publicip #New network
lxc network add publicip ipv4.address 10.3.3.3/30 #add random local IP
lxc network add publicip ipv4.routes 138.*.16.151/32 #add route to the actual public IP that I want to assign to the container
lxc network attach publicip myContainer eth0 #attach it as eth0 interface to the container
lxc config device set myContainer eth0 ipv4.address 10.3.3.2 #assign container local IP from the range of the new network I created with first command
```

Any ideas what I did wrong that my container lost connection to the outside world ?

Output of: lxc network show publicip

```
config:
  ipv4.address: 10.3.3.3/30
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv4.routes: 138.201.16.151/32
  ipv6.address: fd42:cefa:6941:1e25::1/64
  ipv6.nat: "true"
description: ""
name: publicip
type: bridge
used_by:
- /1.0/instances/myContainer
managed: true
status: Created
locations:
- none
```

And output of lxc list:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| myContainer    | RUNNING | 10.3.3.2 (eth0)     | fd42:cefa:6941:1e25:216:3eff:fefe:2e29 (eth1) | CONTAINER | 0         |
|        |         |                     | fd42:cefa:6941:1e25:216:3eff:fe6a:3cdc (eth0) |           |           |
|        |         |                     | fd42:cefa:6941:1e25:216:3eff:fe0d:a57c (eth2) |           |           |
+--------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing the ip from the host's /etc/network/interfaces and adding the IP to the container like this:

```
lxc config device add c1 eth0 nic nictype=routed parent=eth0 ipv4.address=publicIP
```

Comment: How can this be made permanent? To survice reboots?

Comment: It is permanent and it will survive reboots.